# How do Synapse Spark packages interact with the filesystem

Tags: apache-spark, azure-synapse

I'm using the ydata-profiling package with PySpark within a Synapse Spark Pool. Its working just fine BUT I can't get it to export the html of the report to any kind of storage.

If I try the usual Synapse file paths e.g. `profile.to_file('abfss://container_name/file_path')` I just get path not found even though `mssparkutils.fs.ls` on the same path works just fine.

If I do `profile.to_file('file_name.html')` it succeeds but I have no idea where the html file is!

Clearly the package has its own idea of where filesystem root it but can anyone help me discover where that might be or how I can get a package to write elsewhere?

Answer (score 1):

That is because `profile.to_file` supports local paths and doesn't support the `abfss` protocol.

What you can do is create the `.html` file and move or copy it to storage,

or

mount your storage account and write the file to that path.

Whatever is given in the documentation is for Spark, and upon installing
**`fsspec`** and **`adls`** packages, it is supported in pandas.

First approach:

```py
profile.to_file("/tmp/file_name.html")
```

[image]

Next, copy using `mssparkutils.fs.cp`.

```py
mssparkutils.fs.cp("file:/tmp/file_name.html","abfss://<container_name>@<storage_acc_name>.dfs.core.windows.net/profiles/file_name.html")

mssparkutils.fs.ls("abfss://<container_name>@<storage_acc_name>.dfs.core.windows.net/profiles")
```

**Note** - Make sure you prefix `file:` for your local path while copying.

[image]

For the second approach, you can refer to the documentation below to mount the storage account, and you can directly use the mount path like this:

[Introduction to file APIs in Azure Synapse Analytics - Azure Synapse Analytics | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/spark/synapse-file-mount-api#access-files-under-the-mount-point-by-using-the-mssparkutils-fs-api)

`profile.to_file("synfs:/{jobId}/<mount_path>/{filename}")`

Comment: Thank You so much - this is exactly what I was after, an explanation of how the Synapse Spark pool filesystem hangs together.

Answer (score 0):

The convention for using abfss is: `abfss://container@datalake.dfs.core.windows.net/rest_of_file_path_minus_container`

Comment: Thanks, though according to 

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/spark/tutorial-use-pandas-spark-pool

abfs[s]://file_system_name@account_name.dfs.core.windows.net/file_path
 AND 
abfs[s]://container_name/file_path

are both valid syntax. I tried both with the same outcome (path not found!)